# Can we use geofencing on user's current location?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, geofencing, android-geofence

I've seen geofencing examples where the geofence is around a fixed location and wherever someone enters or exit we get a notification.

Can we use geofencing on the user's current location who is constantly moving and whenever any saved location comes within 50 meters, the user gets a notification?

Answer (score 1):

You can meet your requirements using geofences but you have the logic the wrong way round.

Let's call your 'saved location' a 'Point of Interest' (POI). A geofence is a "virtual perimeter for a real-world **geographic area**" (the POI). Geofencing is a "means of notification when a location-aware **mobile device** crosses this virtual perimeter" (the user).

- Create a geofence for each POI. The geofence should be a circle with the POI coordinates at the centre, and with a radius of 50 metres+.
- The user is the mobile device. You track their progress.
- Configure an entry alert notification for each of the POI geofences subscribed to by the user.

If the user enters the geofence they are within 50 metres of the point of interest.

Comment: OK, I have two questions:  
1.Can these POI be added dynamically like the user can create these POIs with the app?    
2.Can the user be POI? Is this possible? like the POI location is updated as the user moves.

Comment: 1. Pretty much anything can be done with programming so yes. 2. You could make the user's location into a geofence, but why in this context would you want to do that? The saved locations won't move to the user, the user moves to them. There are scenarios where you might want to create a geofence around a movable device - we do it to detect unauthorised movement - but it doesn't seem to apply here. If my answer answered your question please click the check mark/tick to accept my answer.

Comment: Hello there, well I tried both of these scenarios.
1. In this I've created multiple geofences but I only get the notification when I enter the last one I enter. But I think I can get through this and make it work.
2. I preferred this scenario to work out particularly because there's limit of 100 geofences per user. I want the user to drop messages at different locations and it may increase 100.So, while working on this I successfully created the geofence around the user's current location but dont know to detect these POIs. Any idea how to proceed further?